# What's causing the colorful artifacts?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, artifacts

I've been using Musgrave textures for years, but in 2.79, I am getting some ugly artifacts along the edges of the object. It doesn't happen in the preview render, only in the final render. Is anyone else getting this? It can easily be recreated by simply connecting a Musgrave texture straight into a diffuse shader and rendering with Cycles.[image: This only happens with Musgrave]

Comment: Everything is ok here. Upload file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, LukeD. @icYou520 suggested I switch off the denoiser, and that took care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just checked with my file and I can verify, it looks like the denoiser is the problem just check it off. Its weird.

[image]

[image]

Its hard to tell with the 2nd picture but there is definitely some weird artifacts. (click image to view them better)

Its real bad with princpled shader

[image]

Comment: Perfect. It is definitely the denoiser. I'll add a bug report so that the devs are aware of it.

Comment: Why is the denoiser doing this?

Comment: Its a bug, it has been reported

Comment: @icYou520 With my build of 2.79a, this bug still hasn't been completely fixed, at least in my renders.