# Denoising is giving my strange artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, denoise

I have this material, that is a subsurface and because some reason when the denoise is applied it gives my really strange artifacts only in the red parts(the oxidized metal is other object).[image]

[image]

Comment: Known bug https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96002/whats-causing-the-colorful-artifacts/96004#96004