# Why do black spots appear on my render?

Tags: rendering

So I was following a tutorial on YouTube on *How to make light bulbs* (by Blender Guru) but when I did the render black spots appeared on the filament
. AND They don't look like noise AT ALL.

You can see them on the glowing bulbs filament and the glass cylinder thing.

Why do they appear and how do I get rid of them?

[image]

enter image description here

[image: note the black spots on][image][image]

These are my settings

Comment: Laldhinthara, could you add a little more information? May be attach your blender file (use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or add screenshots of your render settings (Samples, denoising...) and material setup? This way you would increase your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with denoising in rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering)

Comment: See this post also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96002/whats-causing-the-colorful-artifacts