# Random Distortion-Like in Final Image | Rendering Problem in Blender

Tags: rendering

i already rendered several scenes in blender and this is my first time to encounter this. After the compositing, the rendered image looks weird, some kind of distortion or something. I can't find any answer on google. Is it a bug or something? I use blender 2.83.
Note: the model is a very simple mesh.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. The problem may be because of denoising at a low sample count. To solve it, you can try increasing the sample count to reduce noise.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i will try it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title for your question, specific to the issue

Comment: Hello, please read these questions, you will probably find your answer there. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96002/whats-causing-the-colorful-artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read some comments above and try their suggestion, and the problem is that i have a very low sample count. The solution is of course to increase the sample count. Thanks to them.